# VectorAssembler transformer in spark ML hangs

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

i had a ML pipeline that hanged long time without finishing so i divided the steps and check output of each step.
i found out that the VectorAssembler hangs long time on small dataset
when i run the show() step it hangs forever.
i also validated the issue is not caused because of null values by doing imputation with 0.

```
df2_impute = df2.na.fill(0)
continuousCols = numeric_columns+various_cols+additionalFlds
HashedInputs = [c + "_hashed" for c in categorical_columns] +[d for d in continuousCols if d not in 
               [f for f in date_columns]]
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=HashedInputs,outputCol="features")
df3 =assembler.transform(df2_impute)
df3.show()
```

categorical_columns were hashed with FeatureHasher so they are vectors now.
continuousCols are numeric values.
what can be the cause for that?

Comment: are you using pipeline in any stages? can you show df2_impute? taking so long can be because of wrong column that you are giving. the task is not long, but some input is wrong. could you give me a sample of your df2_impute dataframe somewhere?

Comment: i isolated the problems.
it was with the preceding stage , of featureHasher per categorical column.
from some reason it caused the assember to hang.
when i added repartition to the dataframe before the assembler it finished very quickly. i wonder why the featureHasher created such skewed dataframe.